# Метод одностороннего шифрования данных

Tags: php, java, android, encryption

Необходимо шифровать (в одностороннем порядке) пользовательские данные как на стороне android-приложения, так и на стороне сервера используя средства php. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой метод подойдет. Сейчас я использую MD5, но что-то везде пишут, что он не очень безопасный.

Вообще мне нужен некий хеш данных, а сами данные не нужны.

Comment: Это называется не шифрование, а хеширование. Ну возьмите sha1 или sha256

Comment: Ну или выбирайте тут https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: password_hash еще есть..не обязательно, для паролей. Можно любой текст, хех